# Como receber uma requisição post ou get com typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

eu estou começando com nodejs agora e gostaria de usar typescript para programar compilando para javascript puro. Sendo assim estou tendo dificuldades de encontrar algo sucinto para que eu possa entender (já que sou programador PHP) de como receber requisições post e get. Por exemplo, em PHP uso assim:

`$_POST["foo"]` ou `file_get_contents("php://input")` usando angular e angularjs

ou

`$_GET["foo"]`

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Está usando angular no seu projeto Krint?

Comment: Sim. Estou usando Angular, mas no momento estou desenvolvendo apenas o back-end

Comment: Você quer fazer um requisicao post ou get no back-end ou no front-end? Porque se for no back, voce pode usar o modulo nativo do node. Se for o que vai ser transpilado para o front, ai penso em Angular ou Axios

Comment: Então, na verdade, eu preciso saber como receber informações por post ou get no typescript, entendeu? Por exemplo, o meu front-end manda o cpf do usuário via post e eu preciso saber como receber esse cpf usando typescript com no ambiente do nodejs. Ficou mais claro agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o node.js e express.js para receber post e get.

Instale o express desse modo:
    npm install express

declare uma variável para receber o express()

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

use a função abaixo para receber a requisição GET

```
app.get('/SuaView.extensão', (req, resp) => {

    //Seucódigo
            resp.render("SuaView");
            resp.end();
        });
```

E logo abaixo tem a requisição POST

```
app.post('/SeuPost', (req, resp) => {

    //SeuCódigo

        resp.render("SuaView");
        resp.end();
});
```

O resp.render renderiza a view desejada, caso esteja manipulando alguma informação, você consegue criar uma variável que recebe uma função e preencher um objeto. Para passar ele para a view, você consegue fazer dessa forma: resp.render("SuaView", { NovaVariável: objDaFunção });